# О метке "условные-сокращения"

Tags: обсуждение

У метки "условные-сокращения" нет описания. О чем она? Нужна ли? Заметьте: существует также метка "сокращения".

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что есть смысл сделать главной меткой [сокращения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), а остальные объединить с ней и сделать синонимичными.

Описать можно, например, так:

> Для вопросов о принятых сокращениях, а также о правилах сокращения.

Может быть, найдется вариант получше?

Comment: Описка: Для вопросОВ. В остальном согласен.